# Convert 2016-08-27 string to date in hive

Tags: date, hive, unix-timestamp

I am using the code below to convert it into a date format but my output is always null.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(b.temp,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyyMMdd') as temp1
from 
([![enter image description here][1]][1]
select a.*, regexp_replace(a.ao_date,'-','') as temp
from clla_samp_base a
) b ;
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`2016-08-27` is in the ISO date format which is the only date format acceptable by Hive "as is".

```
hive> select cast ('2016-08-27' as date) as dt; 
OK
dt
2016-08-27
```

P.s.
If you have a column containning values in this format, you can define the column type as DATE in the first place.

Comment: This is not working. I am still getting null in return. My original column has dates in this format "2016-10-16" and has the column type of string_type.

Comment: As you can see this is a tested code. If you still get NULL it means your input is not what you say it is. Show me the result of `hex(your_column)`.

Comment: Hi Dudu, figured it out, the column had dates with double quotes which is the reason it didnt work.  The following code worked              to_date(FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp(ft_cl_date, '"yyyy-MM-dd"'))).  Thanks for the help!